# CentOS: Failing to install PHP-FPM

Tags: centos, php

I'm used to Debian, but this time I'm about to install PHP-FPM on CentOS. I've tried maybe 10 different guides (as this one), but every time I run `yum install php-fpm` I get this output:

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: yum.singlehop.com
 * epel: mirrors.solfo.com
 * extras: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * remi: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * remi-php55: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: mirrors.easynews.com
Setting up Install Process
No package php-fpm available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

This is my `remi.repo`:

```
[remi]
name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/mirror
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php55]
name=Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.5 pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/php55/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/php55/mirror
# WARNING: If you enable this repository, you must also enable "remi"
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-test]
name=Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/test/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/test/mirror
# WARNING: If you enable this repository, you must also enable "remi"
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-debuginfo]
name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - debuginfo
baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/debug-remi/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php55-debuginfo]
name=Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.5 pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - debuginfo
baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/debug-php55/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-test-debuginfo]
name=Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - debuginfo
baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/debug-test/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

And this is my `epel.repo`:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
```

I've also tried `yum clean all` and `yum update` without any success what so ever.

This is driving me crazy. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is showing this type of error,because php-fpm is not available in repo. You can Try this following piece of code.

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-fpm php-mysql
```

Here is the [**Source**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6)

Comment: My files are same as with Ivar. I've done your command but still no change. Not available.